# How to keep Outlook mail unread while consuming email trhough pop3

Tags: php, outlook, pop3

I have an application that retrieve Outlook email in PHP.

It uses part of flourishlib fMailbox to connect to `outlook.office365.com`. We modified it, so we can connect using OAuth2 workflow.

It works correctly but mail appears as “read” in outlook.

Is it possible to keep Outlook mail unread whilst consuming them through Pop3 ?

I tried using IMAP to connect to outlook server, but I can't make it respond to any command I send.

I probably need to set up IMAP right somewhere, but I have like 4 admin for outlook (azure, exchange, outlook, azureAD) and i'm lost.